# TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Any class inheriting Element' - case with overloading

Tags: typescript

In below function delegating click event, the `compoundParameter.eventTargetElementSubtype` is optinal and when not specified, clicked element is being cosidered as instance of basic **Element** class. By TypeScript overloading, theese conditions could be expressed as ...

```js
export default function delegateClickEventHandling(
  compoundParameter: {
    eventTargetSelector: string;
    delegatingContainer: Element | Document;
  },
  handler: (clickedElement: Element, event: MouseEvent) => unknown
): void;

export default function delegateClickEventHandling<ClickTargetElement extends Element>(
  compoundParameter: {
    eventTargetSelector: string;
    delegatingContainer: Element | Document;
    eventTargetElementSubtype: new () => ClickTargetElement;
  },
  handler: (clickedElement: ClickTargetElement, event: MouseEvent) => unknown
): void;
```

The `new () => ClickTargetElement;` means "Any class inheriting from **Element**".

In implementation, I specified default type in `<ClickTargetElement extends Element = Element>` because I expect what without this TypeScript will not understand what is `ClickTargetElement` is in handler when `eventTargetElementSubtype` is undefined.

```js
export default function delegateClickEventHandling<ClickTargetElement extends Element = Element>(
  {
    eventTargetSelector,
    delegatingContainer,
    eventTargetElementSubtype
  }: {
    eventTargetSelector: string;
    delegatingContainer: Element | Document;
    eventTargetElementSubtype?: new () => ClickTargetElement;
  },
  handler: (clickedElement: ClickTargetElement, event: MouseEvent) => unknown
): void {

  delegatingContainer.addEventListener("click", (event: Event): void => {

    if (!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) {
      Logger.logError({
        errorType: UnexpectedEventError.NAME,
        title: UnexpectedEventError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
        description: "We are sorry, but it is a bug. The event is not instance of 'MouseEvent'."
      });
      return;
    }


    for (
      let parentElement: Element | null = event.target as Element;
      parentElement !== null && parentElement !== event.currentTarget;
      parentElement = parentElement.parentElement
    ) {

      if (parentElement.matches(eventTargetSelector)) {

        if (typeof eventTargetElementSubtype === "undefined") {
          handler(parentElement, event);
          return;
        }


        if (!(parentElement instanceof eventTargetElementSubtype)) {
          Logger.logError({
            errorType: UnexpectedEventError.NAME,
            title: UnexpectedEventError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
            description: `Contrary to expectations, the event target is not instance of '${eventTargetElementSubtype.name}'.`,
            occurrenceLocation: "delegateClickEventHandling(compoundParameters, handler)"
          });
          return;
        }


        handler(parentElement, event);
      }
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Inside `if (parentElement.matches(eventTargetSelector)) {`, first I eliminating the case when `eventTargetElementSubtype` is undefined.
Here, TypeScript tells

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClickTargetElement'. 
'Element' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ClickTargetElement', but 'ClickTargetElement' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Element'
```

I expected that thanks to overloading TypeScript will understand that **ClickTargetElement** is **Element**, not **Element**'s inheritor when **eventTargetElementSubtype** is `undefined`.

Of course I will be grateful for the solution, but please exaplain the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I don't understand the TypeScript's logic, but

```
handler: (clickedElement: ClickTargetElement | Element, event: MouseEvent) => unknown
```

works.

### Tests

```js
delegateClickEventHandling(
  {
    eventTargetSelector: ".Example",
    delegatingContainer: document.getElementById("Exmaple") as HTMLElement,
    eventTargetElementSubtype: HTMLButtonElement
  },
  (clickedElement: HTMLButtonElement): void => {
    clickedElement.focus();
  }
);
```

No TypeScript errors. In

```js
delegateClickEventHandling(
  {
    eventTargetSelector: ".Example",
    delegatingContainer: document.getElementById("Exmaple") as HTMLElement
  },
  (clickedElement: HTMLButtonElement): void => {
    clickedElement.focus();
  }
);
```

the error

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call. 

// ...

Property 'eventTargetElementSubtype' is missing in type 
'{ eventTargetSelector: string; delegatingContainer: HTMLElement; }' 
but required in type '{ eventTargetSelector: string; delegatingContainer:
 Element | Document; eventTargetElementSubtype: new () => HTMLButtonElement; }'
```

will be. Finally, in

```js
delegateClickEventHandling(
  {
    eventTargetSelector: ".Example",
    delegatingContainer: document.getElementById("Exmaple") as HTMLElement
  },
  (clickedElement: Element): void => {
    clickedElement.focus();
  }
);
```

will be

```
TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the environment or purpose your script is meant to run in, but the very first thing that sticks out to me would be that you're using a very broad definition.

Based on your specific usage I don't see why you couldn't use `HTMLElement` rather than `Element`. They are both built-in types and part of the DOM library.

`Element` is a very basic type that is essentially a dictionary of definitions that would match every DOM construct. That means that some of the properties you are trying to access may not exist in that type.

I took your code and tested the same script, using `HTMLElement` rather than `Element`, and TS was able to transpile it just fine with changes to nothing but the types. If you **really** want to use `Element`, you could create a custom type definition that **extends** from `Element` and better fits your use case.

**As a general tip,** reading the type definitions can help you a lot when debugging stuff like this.